# How to get a matrix of two dynamic axes

Tags: cntk

I have two tensors, t1 is a 200-dim vector with dynamic axes [batch_len, seq1_len], and t2 is also a 200-dim vector with dynamic axes [batch_len, seq2_len]. I want to get a matrix M of dimension (seq1_len, seq2_len), in which M_ij is the inner product of the two 200-dim vectors t1_i and t2_j. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently (February 2017) there's no way to have two sequence axes. One possibility is to treat the sequence with the shortest range as a tensor with with only static axes.